# Strip characters in bash output

Tags: bash, macos, unix, cross-platform, sh

I have this command which is working for me, which will find zero or one directories in the current directory which match a pattern:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name 'suman-*'| head -n1
```

on MacOS, this will result in something like:

```
./suman-1479860474833
```

`<!EDIT>`

My goal is to find the most recent directory (with the most recent timestamp). The directory contents look like:

```
foo
bar 
baz
suman-1479860475524
suman-1479860471431
suman-1479860474233
...
etc.

</EDIT>
```

I have three questions,

1. Using bash, how can I strip out the `./` characters if they exist in the result? They *should* always be there, but I think always removing the
   first two characters might be too kludgy.
2. Using bash, instead of finding the first result with `head` what is the best way to find the last result? I am guessing it's `tail` but maybe there
   is a better way.
3. Is there a way to only match against a number instead of just using `'suman-*'`? Perhaps I should use `-regex` instead of `-name`?

Now, I could sort the directories by the timestamp in the directory name, or I could potentially sort them by their metadata (if that metadata is accurate and persists through version control updates etc). I am not personally sure that the directory metadata is persistent enough, so I guess would rather be more transparent and use the timestamp in the directory name. *And* it looks like there is no created time in Unix for directories => "In Unix creation time is not stored (only: access, modification and change)."

Comment: `find` has no guaranteed order. You should not use `head` or `tail` to try to find a specific directory.

Comment: What's the actual goal, re "first" or "last"?

Comment: Up to some extent, the first/last issue can be solved by `sort` before `head`...

Comment: BTW -- can we safely assume GNU `find` and `sort` here?

Comment: That last edit was a not-so-subtle change in requirements that invalidated existing answers: please note this change as a comment directly in your question.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy sorry I should have made that more clear, I updated the question - basically I have many suman-<timestamp> directories in the current directory. I want to find the one that is most recent, ordering by timestamp.

Comment: @mklement0 I think Hmedia's answer has had the right idea from the beginning, although I could have been more clear

Comment: @AlexanderMills: Thanks for the edits; on macOS, you don't have access to _GNU_ `find` by default, and if only immediate subdirectories are of interest, a combination of globs and possibly `ls` is simplest.

Comment: @mklement0, boo hiss re: the suggestion of `ls` -- other than mangle your filenames when they contain non-printable characters, what does `ls` do here that `printf '%s\n' */` or `printf '%s\0' */` won't?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: `-r` and `-t` for reverse / last-modified sorting, for convenience (I've added a general caveat re `ls` parsing to my answer).

Comment: @mklement0, ...that's fair, though it also introduces a failure case since you're counting on the full set of glob matches to fit on the command line to `ls`. (And isn't bash guaranteed to honor LC_COLLATE in ordering glob results? So if our numbers have a fixed set of digits, we should be fine off the bat).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Please see the update to my answer.

Comment: @AlexanderMills I've had a play with this on OS X and FreeBSD, as this is actually useful for an application of mine.  See updated answer.  Whether it's the method you employ or not, I'd be curious to know how it works.  If there's anything I've overlooked.  It's worked on an out-of-the-box Mac system, my development mac, and a FreeBSD 10 system.

Answer (score 2):

### Getting the most recently *modified* folder (OS X Compatible):

```
stat -f "%HT %Sm %i" -t %Y%m%d%H%M%S * | grep "^Directory" | cut -f2- -d ' ' | sort -rn | head -1 | cut -f2- -d ' ' | while read inode ; do find . -inum "$inode" | basename "$(cat -)" ; done
```

Result: `suman-1479860475524`

### Getting the most recently named `suman-` timestamp (OS X Compatible):

```
find ./ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "suman-*" -print0 | sort -zn | while IFS= read -d '' file ; do basename "$file" ; done | tail -1
```

Result:

- ```
  suman-1479860475524
  ```

---

**Most recent folder (any name):**

- `stat -f "%HT %Sm %i" -t %Y%m%d%H%M%S *`: Lists folders beginning with a machine readable timestamp in seconds (therefore `cut` can be used safely), and displays the **type, anode, and timestamp** (see https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?stat(1) ):

  - ```
    Directory 20161124051357 17658795
    Directory 20161124051358 17658796
    Directory 20161124051356 17658793
    Directory 20161124051359 17658798
    Directory 20161124051400 17658800
    Directory 20161124051401 17658802
    ```
- `| grep "^Directory" | cut -f2- -d ' '`: Selects folders, and trims off "Directory"
- `| sort -rn`: Numerical sort, newest to oldest
- `| head -1` : Only most recent
- `| cut -f2- -d ' '`: Show only inode component
- `| while read inode ; do find . -inum "$inode" -print0`: Find the file based on the inode (some may argue from this step on is un-necessary, but it returns full folder names in the event of an odd named folder with embedded special characters)

At this point (if we added `; done` here) we would have :

- ```
  ./suman-1479860475524
  ```

So finally

- `| basename "$(cat -)" ; done` : Returns just the **name** of the folder:

  - ```
    suman-1479860475524
    ```

---

**Most recent `suman-` folder timestamp:**

- `find ./ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "suman-*" -print0` : gets the folder names in current folder
- `| sort -zn`: sort them numerically, based on timestamp in directory **name**, not the actual filesystem modified timestamp.
- `while IFS= read -d '' file ; do basename "$file" ; done` : Strip directory location characters and slashes from the file, and output the file list as line separated
- `| tail -1`: just list the most recent one.

In this example, the result happens to be the same:

- ```
  suman-1479860475524
  ```

---

**An example of an odd folder name where the `...while read inode ;`... becomes useful**:

**1.**

- ```
  mkdir $'some \r\t strange \n folder  \n\n name \n  totally nuts'
  ```

**2.**

- ```
  stat -f "%HT %Sm %i" -t %Y%m%d%H%M%S * | grep "^Directory" | cut -f2- -d ' ' | sort -rn | head -1 | cut -f2- -d ' ' | while read inode ; do find . -inum "$inode" -print0 | basename "$(cat -)" ; done
  ```

**3.** (Output)

- ```
  some     strange 
   folder  

   name 
    totally nuts
  ```

---

## The Specific Questions

> Using bash, how can I strip out the ./ characters if they exist in the
>   result? (hoping they should always be there, but I think always
>   removing the first two characters might be too kludgy).

- Use `basename` on the resultant file
- Use `find "$PWD"` instead of `find .` (this will produce full paths)
- Use `-printf "%P"` (this will only show the name part without the `./`) (Note: ***GNU Find Required for `-printf`***)

> Using bash, instead of finding the first result with head what is the
>   best way to find the last result (I am guessing it's tail but maybe
>   there is a better way)

One way is to use:

- First Result: `find ... | sort -n | tail -n1`
- Last Result: `find ... | sort -rn | tail -n1`

(obviously "First" might actually be "Last", depending on it's meaning to you. You could basically substitute `head` command given this fact, as long as you keep it consistent, the `-r` in `sort` will reverse the order, hence the two pipe command sets will give you each a "First" and "Last" result)

> Is there a way to only match against a number (it's a timestamp in
>   millis) instead of just using 'suman-*'? Perhaps I should use -regex
>   instead of -name?

You can just do `-name '*1479860474833'` instead of `-name  'suman-*'`

---

## Alternative (Simpler) approach for ***GNU Find***:

Three test folders for this example:

- suman-14**7**9860474833
- suman-14**8**9860474833
- suman-14**9**9860474833

**Example 1:**

Here's a strict example that mitigates some risks of crazy folder names with embedded special characters

- ```
  find "$PWD" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0 | sort -zn | tail -zn1
  ```

Gives:

- ```
  /my/dir/suman-1499860474833
  ```

**Example 2:**

This strips the leading "./", while keeping the NULL separation, using `printf` and `\0`:

- ```
  find "$PWD" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf "%P \0" | sort -zn | tail -zn1
  ```

Gives:

- ```
  suman-1499860474833
  ```

**NOTE**: `-mindepth 1` avoids returning the parent folder.

Comment: BTW, consider `find ... -print0 | sort -z` to avoid breaking filenames with literal newlines. Granted, this means also needing to use NUL-aware tools on the other side, but the GNU toolchain is well-suited to that; `IFS= read -r -d ''` will do as a bash builtin.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I thought of the `..| while IFS= read -rd '' file ; do ...` but given the specific question it's reasonable to assume OP has a convention for the naming structure.  I've used the NULL flags in my example one, but it's not for every horse IMO.  the -z still needs printing again if it's going to be piped into something that doesn't accept NULL separators, and using loops can be slow.

Comment: *nod*. Loop performance is not as bad in ksh as with bash, but this is all very true.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy For creating a text file of a disks contents that's full of bundles, every nanosecond counts :)

Comment: I don't follow this part: "You can just do -name '\*1479860474833' instead of -name  'suman-*'" The timestamp will vary, and is in fact the thing that I need to sort by

Comment: On MacOS, I get "find: -printf: unknown primary or operator"

Comment: @AlexanderMills: `printf` is _GNU_ `find`-specific, whereas macOS comes with _BSD_ `find`, which has many fewer primaries (actions).

Comment: "The -printf option is not in POSIX find. It is a feature of GNU find, e.g., on Linux."

Comment: @AlexanderMills: If you do need a solution that makes do with _stock_ macOS utilities, please tag your question `osx`. Unless you're specifically looking for a _portable_ solution, you should always add a platform-specific tag. (Conversely, it never hurts to state in the question body that you're looking for cross-platform compatibility.)

Comment: @mklement0 thanks, I tried to make it clear I am on MacOS, but definitely need a cross-platform (*nix) solution

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `find`, if you don't want `./`, you can simply avoid telling `find` to print it.

```
# with GNU find
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name 'suman-*' -printf '%P\n' | head -n1
```

The `%P` format string excludes the part of the filename derived from the argument to `find` -- in this case, the `./`.

With BSD `find`, you don't have that option, but can postprocess once your result is in a shell variable:

```
# strip "./" prefix from filename variable, if and only if it exists
filename=${filename#./}
```

---

As for `head` or `tail`, ordering is not guaranteed, so you can't rely on such options to find a specific file. If you want newest, oldest, first, last, etc., then you'll need to do additional work to achieve this in a reliable way. For instance:

```
IFS= read -r -d '' filename \
  < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name 'suman-*' -printf '%P\0' | sort -z)
```

...will read the first item when the stream is sorted, and...

```
IFS= read -r -d '' filename \
  < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name 'suman-*' -printf '%P\0' | sort -rz)
```

...will sort in the opposite direction, and thus read what would otherwise be the last.

---

#### Portability Notes

Note that neither `find -print0` or `sort -z` is POSIX-specified, but both of these are available both in GNU toolchains and on current MacOS. `find -printf`, by contrast, requires GNU find; this can be installed on MacOS via the macports `findutils` package (which installs it as `gfind`)

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr**

```
printf '%s\n' suman-*/ | tail -n 1 | sed 's|/$||' # ... | cut -d/ -f1 works too
```

---

<sup>Note that this answer assumes that filenames don't have *embedded newlines*, which, fortunately, is rarely a real-world concern.

All commands in this answer are POSIX-compliant, except where noted.</sup>

If you're only looking for *immediate subdirectories* in your target directory, there's no need for `find` - a simple *glob* will do:

```
printf '%s\n' suman-*/ | head -n 1
```

Note, however, that:

- this outputs subdirectory names with a trailing `/`.
- *symlinks* to directories *are* included.
- *hidden* subdirectories are *not* included (not a concern with `suman-*/`, which by definition never matches hidden dirs.) - to include hidden items in general, run `shopt -s dotglob` first (this is a *Bash* extension).
- output sorting is case-*sensitive*, even though the macOS default filesystem is case-*insensitive* - to change that, pipe the `printf` output to  `sort -f` or `sort -rf` before further processing.

Regarding your request to find the most recently *modified* directory matching the pattern, combining `ls -dt` with a glob is the simplest option:

```
ls -dt suman-*/ | head -n 1 # print most recently modified suman-* subdir.
```

If, by contrast, the *timestamps embedded in the directory names* should drive the sorting (e.g., `1479860475524`), *reverse lexical sorting* will do:

```
ls -dr suman-*/ | head -n 1
```

Without the trailing `/`:

```
ls -dr suman-*/ | head -n 1 | sed 's|/$||' # with no path prefix, | cut -d/ -f1 works too
```

A slightly more cumbersome, but **more robust alternative** that avoids use of `ls` in favor of avoiding the max. command-line length when calling *external* utilities, as reported by `getconf ARG_MAX`, which could be a concern if a large number of files match the glob: <sup>Tip of the hat to [Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy).</sup>

```
printf '%s\n' suman-*/ | tail -n 1 | sed 's|/$||'
```

Note: This assumes that `printf` is implemented as a *shell builtin* (as opposed to having to rely on the `printf` *utility*), which, however, is true of all major POSIX-like shells (`bash`, `zsh`, `ksh`, `dash`).

Case-insensitive alternative with `sort` (makes no difference in this scenario):

```
printf '%s\n' suman-*/ | sort -rf | head -n 1 | sed 's|/$||'
```

---

Regarding your 3 original questions:

Re 1): use `sed` to trim the trailing `/`: `printf '%s\n' suman-*/ | head -n 1 | sed 's|/$||'` (if stripping path prefixes is also a concern, it's easiest to `cd` to the path prefix first and then use a filename-only glob).

Re 2): use `printf  ... | tail -1 | ...` to get the lexically last entry (or `printf ... | sort -rf | head -n 1 | ...` to get the lexically last entry irrespective of case).

Re 3): (globbing) patterns allow per-character-position digit matching with character sets such as `[0-9]`, but you cannot apply regex-style quantifiers (duplication symbols) such as `?` and `+` to them.

---

Generally, there are many subtle differences between using `find` and globbing / `ls` - caveat emptor.
Generally, [parsing `ls` output should be avoided](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), but - assuming one is aware of the edge cases and limitations - sometimes it is the most convenient solution.

Comment: Not looking for most recently modified, really just looking for the newest directory, which will always be the one with the most recent timestamp

Comment: @AlexanderMills: Understood, so the `ls -dr` solution, which performs reverse _lexical_ sorting should do, given the fixed-width timestamps embedded in the filenames, preceded by fixed-width prefix `suman-`, right?

Comment: Yeah the timestamps should be fixed-width (until a couple thousand years, I guess). This worked for me: printf '%s\n' suman-*/ | sort -rf | head -1 , but I am not sure how the sort works there

Comment: @AlexanderMills: `-f` sorts case-insensitively (which shouldn't matter in your scenario), and `-r` sorts in _descending_ order; with your embedded timestamps, that means that the most recent timestamp comes _first_.

Comment: thanks, I am cool with the "ls" version - "ls -dr suman-\*/ | head -1", why not just "ls -dr suman-\* | head -1" (without the /) ?

Comment: Why use `ls` at all, if you're expanding the glob before it's ever started? `set -- suman-*/; first_result=$1`. Or, with bash arrays: `files=( suman-*/ ); first_file=${files[0]}`

Comment: ...the above also prevents a failure if you have more matches than will fit on argv.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Fair enough; note that it is the _last_ match that is needed, though. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking that "simpler is better":

```
# 1: Using cut (The option "-c 3-" means "from 3rd character"
find... | cut -c 3-

# 2: You're right, tail is the command (-n1 == -1)
find... | tail -1

# 3: -name should do it:
TIME=1479860474833
find... -name "suman-$TIME"
```

EDIT:

As you said:

> The directory contents look like:
>   
>     `foo
>     bar 
>     baz
>     suman-1479860475524
>     suman-1479860471431
>     suman-1479860474233
>     ...
>     etc.`

**Most recent**

To get the most recent directory, based on name, you can do:

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name suman-\* | cut -c3- | sort -rnk1.7 | head -1
# Result is:
suman-1479860475524
```

And if the content only have directories with name like 'suman*' (never a file with that pattern), then I think this is easier:

```
$ ls -1d suman-* | sort -rnk1.7 | head -1
# Result is:
suman-1479860475524
```

In both cases, the sort option `-r` (reverse) brings the most recent first, and `-k1.7` will sort numerically `-n` from 7th character (millisecond part of name).

**Oldest**

In order to get the oldest directory, based on name, just not use `-r` option:

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name suman-\* | cut -c3- | sort -nk1.7 | head -1
# Result is:
suman-1479860471431

$ ls -1d suman-* | sort -nk1.7 | head -1
# Result is:
suman-1479860471431
```

Comment: What if the file path returned by `find` doesn't start with `./` or contains a full path?

Comment: The OP explicitly said than his command is `find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name 'suman-*'| head -n1`, that means that the output **always** will begin with `./`

Comment: I am searching for the most recent timestamp, I don't know which timestamp I am looking for, beforehand, I am just looking for the most recent one

Comment: @AlexanderMills, ...that being the case, you might find [BashFAQ #3](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003) to be of interest.

Comment: @AlexanderMills, I edited my answer, maybe that's what you're looking for.